# Bare Metal Provisioning

Tags: ubuntu, centos, vmware-esxi, bare-metal

For bare metal provisioning of:

- VMWare ESXi
- Ubuntu
- CentOS

Are Ubuntu MAAS and Spacewalk the only Open Source options for bare metal provisioning or are there other non-proprietary options?

- The solution must be Open Source.
- The solution must be able to at least provision for the three Operating Systems above.
- The solution must be known enough that information on provisioning non-Centos
  systems can be easily found.
- The solution must be "Command Line" friendly so we can perhaps script it

I'm trying to implement one solution for all three (if possible), without having to be locked into any more software licensing.

Currently I'm experimenting with Cobbler which has a lot potential and I could perhaps ansibilize the commands to provision with.

Thanks.

Comment: this is too broad a question, and also a product recommendation request.

Comment: What happened to the other question you already posted on this topic?

Comment: Ahh, found it. You deleted it after it was put on hold. http://serverfault.com/questions/696761/deployment-of-bare-metal-for-vmware-esx-ubuntu-centos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cobbler is the way to go, because it takes care of everything from dynamic DNS, to dhcp. Using snippets you can further customize your installations. Using cobbler you can provision all three of them.

ESXi: http://www.nerdknobs.net/using-cobbler-to-rapidly-deploy-esxi-with-zero-touch-configuration-2/

Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Cobbler/Deployment

CentOS: unixmen.com/setup-pxe-boot-environment-using-cobbler-centos-6-5/